# Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.(C#)

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I am writing an application in C# which looks like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{

    WICForm Frm = new WICForm();

    public MainForm(){}

}
```

Where `_MainForm_` and `_WICForm_` are two different forms in the same application. But when I run the application I get the above error when creating a new instance `Frm` of `WICForm`. What could be the reason?

Comment: What does the WICForm constructor do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Presumably, you are creating a new instance of `MainForm` in the constructor in `WICForm` (or from some code called from within it).

That way the `MainForm` and `WICForm`classes are calling and constructing new instances of each other recursively, which will result in a stack overflow exception.

**Tip:** Put a breakpoint on the line containing `new WICForm();` (place the cursor on that line and press `F9`). When you run the code in debug mode now, you can *step into* that method to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What you said happened to be correct. There was recursion happening unknowingly.